# Mixing Jquery and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Here is my Jquery code:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {     
            onfocus();
            $(".on_off_checkbox").iphoneStyle();
            $('.tip a ').tipsy({gravity: 'sw'});
            $('#login').show().animate({   opacity: 1 }, 2000);
            $('.logo').show().animate({   opacity: 1,top: '30%'}, 800,function(){           
                $('.logo').show().delay(1200).animate({   opacity: 1,top: '0%' }, 300,function(){
                    $('.formLogin').animate({   opacity: 1,left: '0' }, 300);
                    $('.userbox').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200).hide();
                 });        
            })  
        }); 

        $('.userload').click(function(e){
            $('.formLogin').animate({   opacity: 1,left: '0' }, 300);               
              $('.userbox').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200,function(){
                  $('.userbox').hide();             
               });
        });

    $('#but_login').click(function(e){              
          if($('#username_id').val() == "" || $('#password').val() == "")
          {
              showError("Please Input Username / Password");
              $('.inner').jrumble({ x: 4,y: 0,rotation: 0 });   
              $('.inner').trigger('startRumble');
              setTimeout('$(".inner").trigger("stopRumble")',500);
              setTimeout('hideTop()',5000);
              return false;
          }     
         hideTop();
         loading('Checking',1);     
         setTimeout( "unloading()", 2000 );
         setTimeout( "Login()", 2500 );
    }); 

function Login(){
    $("#login").animate({   opacity: 1,top: '49%' }, 200,function(){
         $('.userbox').show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
            $("#login").animate({   opacity: 0,top: '60%' }, 500,function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(200,function(){
                  $(".text_success").slideDown();
                  $("#successLogin").animate({opacity: 1,height: "200px"},500);                  
                });                           
             }) 
     }) 
    //setTimeout( "window.location.href='dashboard.html'", 3000 );
}

$('#alertMessage').click(function(){
    hideTop();
});

function showError(str){
    $('#alertMessage').addClass('error').html(str).stop(true,true).show().animate({ opacity: 1,right: '0'}, 500);   

}

function showSuccess(str){
    $('#alertMessage').removeClass('error').html(str).stop(true,true).show().animate({ opacity: 1,right: '0'}, 500);    
}

function onfocus(){
                if($(window).width()>480) {                   
                        $('.tip input').tipsy({ trigger: 'focus', gravity: 'w' ,live: true});
                }else{
                      $('.tip input').tipsy("hide");
                }
}

function hideTop(){
    $('#alertMessage').animate({ opacity: 0,right: '-20'}, 500,function(){ $(this).hide(); });  
}   

function loading(name,overlay) {  
      $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div><div id="preloader">'+name+'..</div>');
              if(overlay==1){
                $('#overlay').css('opacity',0.1).fadeIn(function(){  $('#preloader').fadeIn();  });
                return  false;
         }
      $('#preloader').fadeIn();   
 }

 function unloading() {  
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast',function(){ $('#overlay').fadeOut(); });
 }
```

Here is my ASP.net code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="formLogin">


          <div class="tip">
                <input name="username" type="text"  id="username_id"  title="Username"   />
          </div>
          <div class="tip">
                <input name="password" type="password" id="password"   title="Password"  />
          </div>

          <div class="loginButton">
            <div style="float:left; margin-left:-9px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="on_off" name="remember" class="on_off_checkbox"  value="1"   />
                <span class="f_help">Remember me</span>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; padding:3px 0; margin-right:-12px;">
              <div> 
                <ul class="uibutton-group">
                   <li><a class="uibutton normal" href="#" id="but_login" >Login</a></li>
                   <li><a class="uibutton normal" href="#" id="forgetpass">forgetpass</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

I am very new to ASP.net and I have the client side validation working to make sure the username or password are not blank.  What I am clueless about is how to now add in the server side validation.

I come from a strong background in classic asp and am taking the leap to ASP.net.  I know the basics like I need to check if username and password are blank, return error if they are.

Do I need runat=server on my but_login?  How do I attach some backend asp.net code so when that link it clicked it processes the server code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you is to replace your typical html input to asp input like this and use client id mode static so you do not have to replace ids in your jquery

it can be like this

```
 <asp:TextBox  name="username" type="text"  id="username_id"  title="Username" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
     <asp:TextBox   name="password" type="password" id="password"   title="Password" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

and code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (username_id.Text == "" || password.Text == "")
            {

                Label1.Text = "Error";

            }
            else
            { 

                    ////

             }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in ASP.NET validation controls automatically provide client side and server side functionality. You may want to consider rewriting your validation using these controls.

Here is a tutorial/overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

**EDIT**

If you cant use built-in validation, you basically need to port all your JavaScript validation to the `Page_Load` event.

```
<script runat=server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string error = ValidatePage();
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            //validation passed, do something
        }
        else
        {
            //validation failed. output error message 
            //via Response.Write or a Label control

            //Response.Write(error);
            //or
            //Label1.Text = error;
        }
    }

    string ValidatePage()
    {
        //validate your elements here. 
        string username = Request.Form["username"];
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            return "Username required";
        }
        //etc...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not an option, since this was a template to speed up the process of site design.  I would only rewrite as a last resort. =(

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a control on the server the control needs to have runat="server" attribute. However if you do this this will change the client id of the control. There are several ways to work around the issue

- select by class intead of id.
- pass the id in a javascript variable using <%= control.ClientID %> and use the variable
- set the control id mode to Static but keep in mind that thi can cause problems if you use the control in databinding and it is repeated more than once on the page.

Another option is to use the ASP.NET validator controls like RegularExpressionValidator and RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: Ok, I added the runat=server to the links.  I went into design view and double clicked it expecting it to take me to the code view making a button click method.  Instead it did nothing.  Any tutorials or code suggestions on how to access a link click in the code behind page? @Stilgar

Comment: Links don't have click event. After all they are simply links. LinkButtons do. The LinkButton control renders an <a> tag with attached JavaScript to do a POST.

Comment: I switched them over to the LinkButton controls and it's getting me farther!  You may have gotten me the push I needed to get this part done.

Comment: Basically when you are using web forms you are often using abstractions over HTML controls and HTTP. For example TextBox means is a kind of wrapper around input type="text". The controls that raise server events are some form of abstraction over POST.